# How to resolve issue: "A dismissed Dismissible widget is still part of the tree" while use Bloc

Tags: flutter, bloc

while implementing `Dismissible` widget I have error while removing an item.

```
    return Dismissible(
      key: Key(widget.product.id),
      onDismissed: (direction) {
        setState(() {
          BlocProvider.of<ManagerBloc>(context)
              .add(RemoveProduct(widget.product));
        });
```

Parent of this child looks like

```
          return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: state.shopItem.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return ProductElement(product: state.shopItem[index]);
              });
        }
```

I moved it to parent and remove `shopItem.removeAt()` with blocProvider but still I got this isseu.
Even if I remove the object using `remove` on the list, it's showing this same error message:

```
    if (event is RemoveProduct) {
      await shopListRepository.remove(event.product);
      yield DefaultDataManager((state as DefaultDataManager)
          .shopItem
          .where((item) => item.id != event.product.id)
          .toList());
    }
```

I tried UniqueKey and it was this same result. My product_id is '64b7ff60-f782-11e9-a3e8-a9ee0aa87ea5' generated by uuid.v1().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is that you are not removing the data model whose list generates the UI **just after (synchronously)** `onDismissed` was called. Let us say you have a `List<Item> _items` in your widget's `State` that stores the UI data model that populates the list. What you have to do in order for `Dismissible` to work is to call `_items.remove(item)` in your `State` synchronously when `onDismissed` is called.

So, do not `await` in between and do not simply remove the item from the repository, remove it from the actual `State` too (I am specifically telling you this because I can see you are doing `await shopListRepository.remove(event.product)`).

Comment: Thanks, It helps me solve the issue. I pass list one level upper and to remove by Bloc I use streamcontroller. Thanks a lot!